# BeautifulSoup - Extract Text Inside Tags using "text="

Tags: search, beautifulsoup, extract, partial, findall

Was reading the book "Web Scraping with Python" and it's decent, but sometimes (frustratingly) glosses over codes readers need to play around with without showing the output nor mentioning relevant limitations.

I spent 4 hours trying to figure out why:

```
fullText.findAll('a', text="bees")
```

returned an empty string regarding the following tag:

```
<a class="search">Why are the bees in my soup bees are bad</a>
```

when the book seemed to suggest it would count how many times "bees" occurred on my bs4.BeautifulSoup page. Only after 4 hours of reading Stack posts and fiddling with codes did I discover that I had to type the **full piece of text** inside text="" to get sort of the desired output. That is **I had to change it to:**

```
fullText.findAll('a', text="Why are the bees in my soup bees are bad")
```

.

.

.

.

Anyway, all I want to ask is a 2 part question:
If I've output all of my  < strong > tags using the following:

```
fullText.findAll('strong')
```

1. [**WITHOUT CONVERTING TO A STRING**] is there a way use findAll or another function to successfully search to see if bees occurs *as part of the text inside the tags **without having to search for the full text inside the tag***
2. is there a BeautifulSoup or other function involved with findAll which will strip the tag definitions from the output and will only display the full text within the tag

I am well aware that the ***2nd question*** has been asked before. Nothing I tried really worked. If you could include your output, that would be great so that I know what I should expect and can compare results if I experience problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `soup.find_all('strong', string=re.compile("bee"))`

This will return a list of all `strong` tags with `"bee"` as part of the text. It uses regex.

2. `string` attribute will do so.

   `soup.find_all('strong')[0].string`

`soup.find_all('strong')` will return a list of all strong tags and thus I indexed it to access a particular tag.

Comment: Thanks so much shiva. Both work and the second one works even better than the question I had posed.
.
I tried reading and experimenting with the python.org documentation for "re" including "compile" both before and after and was absolutely lost. I wish it included "output" so I know what I needed to look for.
.
YouTube videos haven't really helped much either, but I will not take more of your time, will read around, and will post an explanation of what it does when I nail it for other users who are similarly confused. Really, Thanks you so so so much. You saved me quite a huge heartache.

Comment: If this resolves the issue for you then you can accept the answer. N your welcome.

Comment: To be honest, I had no idea what the check mark meant at first.
Answer definitely accepted and thank you.